# How to save the output of a while loop within a for loop in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a for-while-loop combination to check value differences for person-year observations. The entire things gives me a boolean list as outcome which I need for further analysis.

I tried several versions of `append`, none was working.

Here is **my data**:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': ['2001', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009',
                             '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009',
                            '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009'],
                   'id': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 
                          '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2',
                         '5', '5', '5','5', '5', '5', '5'],
                   'money': ['15', '15', '15', '21', '21', '21', '21', 
                             '17', '17', '17', '20', '17', '17', '17',
                            '25', '30', '22', '25', '8', '7', '12']}).astype(int)
```

Here is **my code**:

```py
# for every person
for i in df.id.unique():
    # find the first and last index value
    first = df[df['id']==i].index.values.astype(int)[0] 
    last = df[df['id']==i].index.values.astype(int)[-1] 
    # first element has to be kept
    print(False)
    # for all elements, compare values next to each other
    while first < last:
        abs_diff = abs( df['money'][first] - df['money'][first+1] ) > 0
        # print TRUE, when adjacent values differ
        print(abs_diff)
        # update the counter
        first +=1
```

It returns a boolean list namely: 
 FalseFalseFalseTrueFalseFalseFalseFalseFalseFalseTrueTrueFalseFalseFalseTrueTrueTrueTrueTrueTrue

**Question**: How can I save that loop output in a list?

Comment: What's wrong with just appending to a list or did you want each person to have their own list of abs_diff's?

Comment: This is typical case of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Take a step back and describe what you want to do, not why **your** solution is not working. There is most likely a more easier and vectorized solution available. Try to add an expected output.

Comment: @Erfan thanks for your feedback. The question formular asked users to not only state the question but also  "Provide background including what you've already tried". I tried `append`. Still I hoped my Question (in bold) was clear stated. I will improve next time :) regards

Comment: IIUC, you're just looking for something like `df.groupby('id')['money'].diff().gt(0)` no need for nested loops

Comment: Take 30 second to read the link I provided. Step 1 you did correct, you provided example data. Second: describe what you want to achieve with expected output as data as well. Now you pasted your code as problem description. As you can see, your problem is probably a one liner like @ChrisA his suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html), [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and [`ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html):

```
df.groupby('id')['money'].diff().fillna(0).ne(0).to_list()
```

[out]

```
[False,
 False,
 False,
 True,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 True,
 True,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 True,
 True,
 True,
 True,
 True,
 True]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for improving the code in general. I will test it for several versions with my data. Sometimes ID/values are missings etc.

Comment: Here's the proof of what I'm trying to bring over to you @MarcoDoe

Comment: @Erfan I posted the entire problem as well. Since I got no answers, I started to build some code. I found that code-related questions are answered quicker and more extensive than problem-descriptions. Again, I now read through the XY-Problem. Thanks for feedback

Comment: Chris, how can I adjust your code to first check if the difference is really small (say 5) and if so assign it its precursor value (i.e. smoothing the data)?

Comment: to check for difference less than 5, you could do something like `df.groupby('id')['money'].diff().fillna(0).abs().between(1, 5)` (this will be`True` for small difference of less than 5, but `False` for no difference). You could then `NaN` these values out and use [`Series.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) (forward-fill) to propagate the precursor values forward

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': ['2001', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009',
                             '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009',
                            '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009'],
                   'id': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1',
                          '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2',
                         '5', '5', '5','5', '5', '5', '5'],
                   'money': ['15', '15', '15', '21', '21', '21', '21',
                             '17', '17', '17', '20', '17', '17', '17',
                            '25', '30', '22', '25', '8', '7', '12']}).astype(int)
# for every person
l=list()
for i in df.id.unique():
    # find the first and last index value
    first = df[df['id']==i].index.values.astype(int)[0]
    last = df[df['id']==i].index.values.astype(int)[-1]
    # first element has to be kept
    print(False)
    l.append(False)
    # my try: diff = []

    # for all elements, compare values next to each other
    while first < last:
        abs_diff = abs( df['money'][first] - df['money'][first+1] ) > 0
        # print TRUE, when adjacent values differ
        l.append(abs_diff)
        # my try: diff.append(abs_diff)

        # update the counter
        first +=1
print(l)
```

output:

```
[False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, True, False, False, False, True, True, True, True, True, True]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you just need to define the variable outside of the `for` loop:

```
output = list()

for i in df.id.unique():
    # find the first and last index value
    first = df[df['id']==i].index.values.astype(int)[0] 
    last = df[df['id']==i].index.values.astype(int)[-1] 
    # first element has to be kept
    output.append(False)

    # for all elements, compare values next to each other
    while first < last:
        abs_diff = abs( df['money'][first] - df['money'][first+1] ) > 0
        # print TRUE, when adjacent values differ
        output.append(abs_diff)

        # update the counter
        first +=1
print(output)
```

At the moment you're resetting the value each time through, so that you only end up with the output for the last `id`.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)
for i in df.id.unique():
    # find the first and last index value
    first = df[df['id']==i].index.values.astype(int)[0] 
    last = df[df['id']==i].index.values.astype(int)[-1] 
    # first element has to be kept
    print(False)
    result.append("False")

    # my try: diff = [] 

    # for all elements, compare values next to each other
    while first < last:
        abs_diff = abs( df['money'][first] - df['money'][first+1] ) > 0
        # print TRUE, when adjacent values differ
        print(abs_diff)
        result[i].append(abs_diff)

        # my try: diff.append(abs_diff)

        # update the counter
        first +=1
```

I guess it will work if you want to save id for each person individually.